# a separate site for a Sharepoint data connection library - why?

Tags: 2010, document-library, infopath, library, data-connection

Step 1 of procedure "To create a SharePoint Data Connection Library" in msdn article [How to: Create and Use a Data Connection Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms772101.aspx) tells:

- "1. Browse to an SharePoint Server 2010 site on which you have at least Design permissions. If you are on the root site, create a new site before you continue with the next step"

Why does a Sharepoint Data Connection Library require a separate site for itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could connect to any SharePoint site where you already have created a Data Connection Library, so no actual need to create a site just for it.

Comment: I knew that I could, since I already created Data Connection Libraries before, without creating sites for them but my question was why or what's for to create a separate site. I am not grasping any possible sense of this

Comment: the reasons could be multiple, by example using them from Excel Services, or PerformancePoint which could both act across sites easily.

Comment: Sorry, I am still not getting why to have a separate site for these reasons

Comment: The phrasing could be what misleads you. Actually it simply states that if you want, you could do it!

Answer (score 1):

Might the reason for this "create a new site first" instruction be that many users' root sites are based on the PowerPivot site template? This template omits the Data Connection Library option. The root site uses this template by default if the initial farm setup was done with the SQL Server 2012 (or 2008?) PowerPivot for SharePoint installation wizard rather than with the standard SharePoint 2010 Products Configuration Wizard.

Maybe rather than this longwinded explanation, whoever wrote the data connection instructions thought it was simpler just to suggest starting fresh with a new site.